# Can the damage or accuracy of the Pyroconverger be increased?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The [*pyroconverger*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/pyroconverger) is a "magic" item (GGR, p 180) that allows a character to:

> As an action, you can cause the *pyroconverger* to project fire in a 10-foot cone.

**Are there other magical items that allow one to increase the damage, potency, or DC of this item?** Similar to how one would use *bracers of archery* to improve attacks from their longbow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are making the *pyroconverger* project the fire, no items or abilities that boost your fire damage or DCs will work, and I haven't come across any magic items that would increase another magic item's damage or DC specifically.

At best, I believe you would have to (if your DM allows it) buy or craft a scroll/wand/staff of spells like [*Elemental Bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-bane) or [*Hallow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) which can increase the fire damage a target will take, or spells like [*Bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) and [*Bestow Curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse) to make it harder for them to make the save.

You could also look for magic items that can give a creature disadvantage on dexterity saving throws such as anything that will restrain or exhaust them; or even items that might cause stun or paralyze which will cause them to fail dexterity saves altogether (although in those cases you've probably got faster ways to end the combat than using the pyroconverger as a follow-up).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.